# Predicting label with KNN in Python

Tags: python, knn

I'm trying to predict correct label with KNN; but for some reason it's not working. Can someone please advise what I did wrong?

```
def eucledian_dist(dist1, dist2):
  return(np.sqrt(np.sum((dist1- dist2)**2)))

def knn(val, k, train, labels):
    distances = [eucledian_dist(val, img) for img in train]
    nearest = np.argsort(distances)[:k]
    class = np.bincount(labels[nearest])
    prediction = np.argmax(class)
    return prediction
```

Comment: class is a reserved word in python, so you are not supposed to use it in this context. Use other names for variables like "nearest_classes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `class` as a name for your variable because it is used to define [class in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

You always can change it in your code and choose another name. Or there is a common way to work with it. Just add `_` to the end of a keyword, like: `class_`.